# What's the benefit of injecting actionCreators versus a mapDispatchToProps?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm skimming the [`connect` docs](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#examples) and trying to understand this example:

> **Inject todos and all action creators**
>
> ```
> import * as actionCreators from './actionCreators'
>
> function mapStateToProps(state) {
>   return { todos: state.todos }
> }
>
> export default connect(mapStateToProps, actionCreators)(TodoApp)
> ```

Why is `mapDispatchToProps` not necessary here?  Where is `dispatch`?

I understand actions, `dispatch`, and `mapDispatchToProps`, but I'm a little bit fuzzy on Action Creators and the above syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass `Object` or `Function`:

**If an object is passed**, each function inside it is assumed to be a Redux action creator. `Connect` will bind аction сreators to `dispatch` for you.

```
import * as actionCreators from './actionCreators';

connect(mapStateToProps, actionCreators)(TodoApp)
```

and then in component

```
this.props.someActionCreator();
```

**If a function is passed**, it will be given dispatch. It’s up to you to return an object that somehow uses dispatch to bind action creators in your own way. You may use the `bindActionCreators()` helper from Redux.
If `ownProps` is specified as a second argument, its value will be the props passed to your component, and `mapDispatchToProps` will be re-invoked whenever the component receives new props.

```
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return { actions: bindActionCreators(actionCreators, dispatch) }
}
```

**If you omit it**, the default implementation just injects dispatch into your component’s props.

then in component:

```
this.props.dispatch(someActionCreator());
```

[source react-redux DOCS](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md)

**Therefore**, the benefit of injecting object of actionCreators over a function, is more convenient and concise form of passing actionCrators to component

Comment: I see... it's also critical that `import * as actionCreators from './actionCreators';` actually sets actionCreators equal to an object with functions exported in `./actionCreators` as properties. So, in this case it's your first example being implemented